# react native : there is way to use axios.put?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

in my code here i try to make "put" with axios but i dont sure its the way to do it.
i wanna know please what is the best way to use `put` .
as you can see i use the `componentdidmount` to fire the `putData()` function .

```
export default class WaterQualitySamplesScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }


  // //post//////////////////////////////////
    putData = () => {
        const axios = require('axios')

        axios.put('https://harigotphat1.mekorot.co.il/m200_orderapprovehub/api/Installation?Platform=fcm&InstallationId=o-ritzhak&Handle=ExponentPushToken[JtL6KhGx8JxPeF3rO005WY]',
        { headers: {
          Authorization: 'Bearer ' + "my token"}
        })
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            })
    }
    // ///////////////////////////////////

  registerForPushNotificationsAsync = async () => {
    const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);
    if (status !== "granted") {
      alert("No notification permissions!");
      return;
    }

    try {
      // Get the token that identifies this device
      let token = await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync();
      console.log("this is my token:", token);

      firebase
        .database()
        .ref("users/" + "/push_token")
        .set(token);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  //////////////

  async componentDidMount() {
    this.currentUser = await firebase.auth().currentUser;
    await this.registerForPushNotificationsAsync();

    this.putData();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.screen}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            this.props.navigation.navigate({ routeName: "PLACES" });
          }}
          style={styles.button}
        >
          <Text style={styles.textButton}>TODO</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            this.props.navigation.navigate({ routeName: "  " });
          }}
          style={styles.button}
        >
          <Text style={styles.textButton}>SAID</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <View style={styles.InfoTableBottomMainContainer}>
          <View style={styles.InfoTableBottomView}></View>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is your problem with axios put? Axios put should work like that, are you sure  that your backend server is working well with put one?

Comment: i need to know my "azure token" to use it inside the "putData ()" .
this is the link to thr library im use :
[link](https://github.com/shedaltd/react-native-azure-ad-2)
how can i get my token from there ?

Answer (score 1):

```
export const axiosPutReq = (url, data, authenticationId) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    axios({
      method: "put",
      url,
      data,
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer " + authenticationId,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json"
      }
    })
      .then(response => {
        resolve(response.data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        reject(error);
      });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

My code snippet:

```
  const authFetch = async (data) => {
  var header = {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    Authorization: 'authToken',
    //  access_token: data.data.token,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  };
  0;
  //
  await AsyncStorage.getItem('accessToken').then((resp) => {
    header['accesstoken'] = resp;
  });
  //console.log(header)

  if (data.method == 'POST' || data.method == 'PUT') {
    return fetch(`${data.url}`, {
      method: data.method,
      headers: header,
      body: JSON.stringify(data.data),
    });
  } else {
    return fetch(`${data.url}`, {
      method: data.method,
      headers: header,
    });
  }
};
export default authFetch;
```

> use this authFetch method like this:

```
  export function yourFunctionName(data) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
  return new Promise((success, failure) => {
    authFetch({
      url: `${baseUrl}endpoint`,
      data: data,
      method: 'PUT',
    })
      .then((res) => {
        res.json().then((result) => {
          success(result);
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        failure(err);
      });
  });
}
```